# I have text file and I want to extract data which proceeds after a certain word and ends before another word. How do I do this python?

Tags: python, regex, extract

Specifically here, the latitude would be - 19.041691972000024

And the longitude would be - 72.85052482000003

```
var marker_82a31b114c0243859e73c4f5f1332554 = L.marker
[19.047690380000063, 72.85787174600006],

.addTofeature_group_ad623471194f451d9f1cf7fc718747c5
```

Comment: If always within square brackets, this shouldn't be too hard. Maybe just [`\[(.*),\s*(.*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/VMEk5X/1)

Comment: Formatting has been improved.